# rollback module migration in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, migration

I've run migration for a laravel module by

```
php artisan module:migrate
```

Then I wanted a rollback, so I've tried

```
php artisan module:rollback
```

There was no such command so I tried

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

But Laravel doesn't see it:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
 Class 'AddInteractionsToVisits' not found
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to rollback module migration?

Comment: try **composer dump-autoload**

Comment: I think you have a migration that has been named incorrectly. `*_add_interactions_to_visits`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using a package, you should check their docs.

`php artisan module:migrate-rollback Module`

Check here https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v1/advanced-tools/artisan-commands

Answer (score 0):

And if you need to rollback specific migration from module you can do this.

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --path=Modules/YourModule/database/migrations/2020_05_15_xxxxxx_create_your_table.php
```

I have use this code here instead Module doc code since it's giving an error.

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --path=...
```

And remember, If you are using linux servers careful about case sensitivity. You have to add like **/Database/Migrations** with starting capital.

```
/Database/Migrations/2020_05_15_xxxxxx_create_your_table.php
```